# How to print on a receipt printer over the network in Fast Report correctly

Tags: delphi, fastreport

If the printer is connected to the computer I have no problem printing receipts, but if the printer is over the network(shared locally) the print-out prints incorrectly.
What did I miss?

Picture 1 - printer is connected to the computer
Picture 2 - Printer is not connected to the computer

[image]

Comment: Picture 1 - printer is connected to the computer, Picture 2 - printer is a shared receipt printer

Comment: I would blame either drivers or fonts. Are you using a font which is compatible with your printer? Is that font available on the remote computer? Either way, I can tell the font is not the same on both samples.

Comment: Sorry about that.. i forget to hide the name of the cashier in my first post so I somewhat panicked. Anyway, the font is Arial, I believe I have no problem with fonts. We installed same printer driver in both computer.

Comment: Whatever receipt printer you're using should give you a list of preferred fonts. Is Arial one of those? Take a look here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20027/what-font-is-typically-used-for-receipts

Comment: Also see here, from Microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/201978

Comment: How do I know the preferred fonts of a printer? Search google and "Devices and Printers" but no avail.

Comment: Try this for example, drop a TButton and two TListBox controls: http://pastebin.com/V63M5nMn The left list will show you the printers, and on the right, will show you the fonts supported by the selected printer.

Comment: The premise of your question is that the reason for the different appearance is the location of the printer. Is that *really* your assertion? From the pictures, it looks to me like you're comparing two entirely different printers. At the very least, they're printing different data. I would expect you'd print the *same* thing to the *same* printer, changing *only* its location.

Comment: If the printers are the same model and are configured the same way, where they're located (locally or across a network) is irrelevant. A printer is a printer is a printer, whether it's on your desk or on the other side of the planet. Your images clearly shows that either the printers are not the same or that they're configured very differently. None of that is an issue with Delphi. It's an issue with the printer, the printer drivers, or the printer configuration.

Comment: And who upvoted a question that has no details, no code, no content except two images, and zero details other than *one printer is local and one is a network printer*?

Comment: @KenWhite I see somebody knows the 17th rule of acquisition!

Comment: @Jerry: Not a DS9 fan. More NextGen. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the font used in picture 1 is a proportional font, but in picture 2 it is a monospaced font.  Perhaps you should try to use a monospaced font in the FastReport design template.